# package inputenc error unicode char (u + 190) not set up for use with latex

Tags: errors

Help, package `inputenc` error:

> unicode char (u+190) not set up for use with latex.

I use `\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}`

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2):

The glyph is identical to a Cyrillic character:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[X2,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}

\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\CYREPS}{X2}
\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\cyreps}{X2}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0190}{\CYREPS}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{025B}{\cyreps}

\begin{document}

ABCDEƐF

abcdeɛf

\end{document}
```

[image]